# IEnumerator skips the code after yield return new WaitForSeconds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ienumerator, yield-return

I am trying to use coroutines to spawn cubes in my game by following Unity Learn tutorials but altougj I did everything same as it is in the tutorial the code does not work and skips the code after yield return new WaitForSeconds. I already looked to questions in stackoverflow and only I could find is someone with the same problem but one and only accepted answer is " "probably" killing the scene before the WaitForSeconds-inputed time pass" and the code is true but there is something wrong in the scene. So, as a newbie Unity and C# user I could not solve it.

I used this code for difficulty buttons in my game;

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class DifficultyButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameManager gameManager;
    private Button button;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        button = GetComponent<Button>();
        button.onClick.AddListener(SetDifficulty);
        gameManager = GameObject.Find("Game Manager").GetComponent<GameManager>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    void SetDifficulty()
    {
        Debug.Log(gameObject.name + " was clicked");
        gameManager.StartGame();
    }
}
```

And the GameManager script used in this button script is this;

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms.Impl;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> targets = new List<GameObject>(4);
    public TextMeshProUGUI scoreText;
    public TextMeshProUGUI gameOverText;
    public Button restartButton;
    public bool isGameActive;

    private float score = 0;
    private float spawnRate = 1.0f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    IEnumerator SpawnTarget() 
    {
        Debug.Log("hop ordayım");
        Debug.Log("isGameActive: " + isGameActive);
        while (isGameActive)
        {
            Debug.Log("Sonunda burdayım");
            
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnRate);
            Debug.Log("Buraya da geldim");
            int index = Random.Range(0 ,targets.Count);
            Debug.Log("Buraya da");
            Instantiate(targets[index]);
            Debug.Log("cok sukur be");
        }

    }

    public void UpdateScore(int scoreToAdd) 
    {
        score += scoreToAdd;
        scoreText.text = "Score:" + score;
    }

    public void GameOver() 
    {
        gameOverText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        restartButton.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        isGameActive = false;
    }

    public void RestartGame()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }

    public void StartGame()
    {
        isGameActive = true;
        StartCoroutine(SpawnTarget());
        Debug.Log("geldim");
        UpdateScore(0);
    }
}
```

I used Debug.Log's to see what is happening and the output when I clicked the easy button is this;

```
Easy Button was clicked
hop ordayım
isGameActive: True
Sonunda burdayım
geldim
```

So it does not continue after printing "geldim" altough I wait more than 1 seconds after "geldim" printed;

Expected output;

```
...
geldim
Buraya da geldim
Buraya da
cok sukur be
```

Why is this happening and what can I do about this?

Comment: well yes, the coroutine starts and the next line says print geldim (unknown word to me) but yes it will . the coroutine will only pause the code in the coroutine not outside it

Comment: @BugFinder     Oh, I am sorry that I am confused about expected output, I understood what you say but still code does not work as expected, because according to thing you said otuput should be 
` Sonunda burdayım,geldim, (after 1 second), Buraya da geldim, Buraya da, cok sukur be`  but it still does not print the part after 'geldim'. Why is that?

Comment: The `return` keyword will make the code execution down to the end of the block so it will not be executed what is between the return and the end block. (yield won't change this behaviour of return)

Comment: Usually, Unity learners skip the basics of the language itself. A little tutorial about C# will improve your unity experience a lot.

Comment: @Eldar About that yield does not change the behaviour part, until I used another metod instead of Start() to call StartCoroutine() the part between yield return and the end of the IEnumerator block was running normally, so it did not skip the code as you said. But when I used StartCoroutine inside of my custom StartGame() function that skipping problem started to happen. Why is that? And thanks for C# studying suggestion I really need that :)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Eldar no! `yield return` works completely different to a normal method's `return`! A `yield return` returns a new value while iterating the `IEnumerator` .. what you are referring to would be a `yield break;` ... in this case of a Coroutine a `yield return` basically kinda behaves similar to an `await` (not c# but behavior wise)

Comment: Do you anywhere play with the [`Time.timeScale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html)? The `WaitForSeconds` is affected by it .. also if this object is disabled/destroyed unloaded  (e.g. due to scene load) in the meantime the routine will not be continued

Comment: @derHugo no I do not play with Time.timeScale anywhere but I will check the second thing you said now, thank you very much :)

Comment: @derHugo I checked the scene thing, the IEnumerator is in the GameManager script and that script is attached to GameManager object which is always in the scene. So, i could not spot he problem. But I realised that when I click to the button (which has DifficultButton script attached) the game runs for a very brief moment and I see "Score: 0" instead of just "Score:" but it is just looks like a blink.

Comment: Does there maybe also a `RestartGame` call happen which reloads your scene -> all previous things are unloaded and you now have a new instance of the gameManager where the Coroutine isn't running yet?

Comment: @derHugo ooooou thanks for that i did not realise that I will try to solve it now. Thank you very much.

Comment: @derHugo I finally solved the problem thank you very much! Can you write it as an answer instead of a comment so I can choose it as an asker approved(?) solution for other people with same problem :)

Answer (score -1):

add yield return null to the end

Comment: This wouldn't change anything ..